# Replace a specified portion of a string

Tags: php, string, str-replace

How can I use str_replace method for replacing a specified portion(between two substrings).
For example,

```
string1="www.example.com?test=abc&var=55";
string2="www.example.com?test=xyz&var=55";
```

I want to replace the string between `'?------&'` in the url with `?res=pqrs&`. Are there any other methods available?

Comment: you need to specify the details how you want to extract the portion, like what it begins with, what it ends with, etc.

Comment: You want to replace or remove it ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dirty version:

```
$start = strpos($string1, '?');
$end = strpos($string1, '&');

echo substr($string1, 0, $start+1) . '--replace--' . substr($string1, $end);
```

Better:

```
preg_replace('/\?[^&]+&/', '?--replace--&', $string1);
```

Depending on whether you want to keep the `?` and `&`, the regex can be mofidied, but it would be quicker to repeat them in the replaced string.

Answer (score 2):

You could use [`preg_replace`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) to do that, but is that really what you are trying to do here?

```
$str = preg_replace('/\?.*?&/', '?', $input);
```

If the question is really "I want to remove the `test` parameter from the query string" then a more robust alternative would be to use some string manipulation, [`parse_url`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php) or [`parse_str`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php) and [`http_build_query`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-query.php) instead:

```
list($path, $query) = explode('?', $input, 2);
parse_str($query, $parameters);
unset($parameters['test']);
$str = $path.'?'.http_build_query($parameters);
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you're working with URL's, you can decompose the URL first, remove what you need and put it back together like so:

```
$string1="www.example.com?test=abc&var=55";

// fetch the part after ?
$qs = parse_url($string1, PHP_URL_QUERY);

// turn it into an associative array    
parse_str($qs, $a);
unset($a['test']); // remove test=abc
$a['res'] = 'pqrs'; // add res=pqrs

// put it back together
echo substr($string1, 0, -strlen($qs)) . http_build_query($a);
```

There's probably a few gotchas here and there; you may want to cater for edge cases, etc. but this works on the given inputs.

Answer (score 0):

Think of [regex](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php)

```
<?php
$string = 'www.example.com?test=abc&var=55';
$pattern = '/(.*)\?.*&(.*)/i';
$replacement = '$1$2';
$replaced = preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $string);
?>
```